# Gimp produces hundreds of subprocesses running gimpgpui2.exe

Tags: windows, gimp

I installed gimp 2.8.22 on Windows 10, 64-bit.

When I run gimp, I get the initialization window, which queries fonts, then plugins. Gimp gets stuck at the plugin gimpgpui2.exe, producing hundreds of copies of gimpgpui2.exe. Eventually, Microsoft says Gimp is unresponsive, and it asks if I want to terminate the program. I say yes, but the Task Manager shows hundreds of gimpgpui2.exe processes still running. (There were 322 this last time!)

To kill it, I have to open a command window and type:

```
taskkill /f /im gimp*
```

That gets rid of most of them, but I have to run it a second time because more processes appear.

Any idea of how to get gimp to run without this problem?

Comment: Why are you trying to install/run an old version of Gimp (from 08-May-2017) when the latest version is [2.10.0 (2018-04-27)](https://www.gimp.org/downloads/)?

Comment: Curious...I downloaded it only 2 weeks ago, via bittorrent. I'm surprised I asked for an old version.

Comment: I downloaded and installed 2.10.0. When running for the first time, I get the message:
gimpgpui2.exe - Application Error
The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000007b).
Click OK to close the application.

Comment: This plug-in does not come with GIMP, so you have installed it yourself, probably as part of a plug-in pack. Do you know what it is supposed to do?

Comment: gimpgpui2.exe comes from gutenprint

Comment: You might be one of very few users (maybe even the only one) to run gutenprint on the Windows platform. Did you file a bug report with the gutenprint developers and/or the maintainer of the Windows build of this plug-in?